# How to filter array with specific key react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array like below:

```
const data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
...
]
```

What I want to do is this. Suppose, I only want to see the conversation between user1 and user 2.

So I want to filter the array and make a new array which will contain only those data where sender is **user1** and receiver is **user2** or sender is **user2** and receiver is **user1**.

I think, it can be done using map or stuff like that but I actually have no idea. I am new to React Native.

Comment: Question authors are not obligated to "accept" an answer. However, we prefer it if an author does accept an answer, since this removes the question out of the unanswered lists and API feeds. You don't need to worry about favouritism when accepting - just choose one thought was most helpful or explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = []

getSenderRec = (user1, user2) => {
    data.filter(data => {
        if (user1 === data.sender && user2 === data.receiver || user2 === data.sender && user1 === data.receiver){
                result.push(data)
            }
        }   
    )
}
const data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
]

getSenderRec('user1', 'user2')

console.log(result)
```

Here is your `console.log(result)` output:

```
[ { id: '1', sender: 'user1', receiver: 'user2', msg: 'hello!' },
  { id: '2', sender: 'user2', receiver: 'user1', msg: 'yo!' } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the second quickest answer!! I am going to test it right now! I will vote up then :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.filter`. The callback returns a boolean:

```
const data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
];

function filterData(data) {
    return data.filter((x) => (x.sender === 'user1' && x.receiver === 'user2') || (x.sender === 'user2' && x.receiver ===  'user2'));
}

const result = filterData(data);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Gonna test all and inform you all :D

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@nothingtosay/courageous-orange this shows this worst error :(

Answer (score 1):

```
You need just use filter for array

const data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
]

const result = data.filter(rec => {
  if (rec.sender === 'user1' && rec.receiver === 'user2') {
    return rec
  }
  if (rec.sender === 'user2' && rec.receiver === 'user1') {
    return rec
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quickest reply! I am going to test it right now! :)

Comment: This shows Objects are not valid as react childs :(

Comment: this shows this worst error D: https://snack.expo.io/@nothingtosay/joyous-donut

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain an `array` of `users` and based on that you can filter the array:

```js
var data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
];
var users=['user1', 'user2'];

var result = data.filter(chat=>users.includes(chat.sender) && users.includes(chat.receiver));

console.log(result);
```

Or You can also have an array of filters maintained for `keys` of the object. It will short the code even more. Here it is:

```js
var data = [
    {"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
    {"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
    {"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
    {"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
];

var users=['user1', 'user2'];
var filters=['sender', 'receiver'];

var result = data.filter(chat=>filters.every(k=>users.includes(chat[k])));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Uh!! This community is awesome!! I gonna test all these three and let you all know my votes :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like below

```
 const data = [
{"id":"1", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user2", "msg":"hello!"},
{"id":"2", "sender":"user2", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"yo!"},
{"id":"3", "sender":"user3", "receiver":"user1", "msg":"hi!!"},
{"id":"4", "sender":"user1", "receiver":"user3", "msg":"hmm"},
...
]

let filtereddata = data.filter((el)=>{
    return el.sender === "user1" && el.receiver === "user2"
    
})
```

here filtereddata will have only result which you wanted to show

Comment: Thanks!! Gonna test it and let you all know :)

Comment: This shows this horrible error: https://snack.expo.io/@nothingtosay/crabby-apple plz help :(

Comment: the code you have sent is class based component and you cann't declare your const variable like that either move it to componentDidMount() or any other function that need to be declared inside your react class component it will work

Comment: Anku I made some updates, please check it now. it still shows the same

Comment: You need to make a minor change when you are showing your data in render function you are printing the whole object i mean like this <Text>{this.state.data}</Text> but you need to extract some specific value from the array and print like {this.state.data[0].id}

Comment: or  you can loop through your filtered data using map function and print all the data like this.state.data.map((key,value)=>{return(<Text>{value.msg}</Text>)})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216743/discussion-between-anku-and-nothingtosay).